# datepicker minimal year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a DatePicker minimum year is 2000 and needs to be done so that the minimum year was equal to, well, for example, 1910

[image]

```
$(" .datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true});
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try clicking on year 2000. And then try selecting year again. You should be able to select 1990. And you can repeat that 10 times.

Or, use the `yearRange` option. More info [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange).

Example:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearRange: '1910:2010' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepickerID" ).datepicker({   
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1930:2014'
    });
});
```